# Много процессов MySqld

Tags: php, mysql, vkontakte-api, nginx

Подскажите пожалуйста, откуда столько процессов MySqld?

Когда делаешь Reboot, то процессов мало и ОЗУ около 200. Проходит сутки и уже такая картина.

На сервере стоят боты VK, один бот модератор следит за спамом в группе. Другой отвечает в ЛС. И ещё один парсит данные групп, статистику, записи на стене и так по мелочи ещё не которые вещи.

Система Debian 9, nginx, php7-fpm. Не какой оптимизации не делал, установил систему, поставил пакет LEMP и настроил домены и в php.ini по мелочи поправил. Происходит много запросов в MySql для проверки актуальности данных.

Запрос на парсинг делается каждую минуту. Скрипт работает от 3 до 10 секунд, потом 50 секунд простаивает, новая минута новые запросы и так по кругу.

Что можете сказать, откуда такая забивка MySql? Я до того пока не пришел сюда, прочел что это происходит из-за кеширования самых частых запросов, может быть из за этого? и что с этим делать?

Спасибо за внимание!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После reboot:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а покажите просто `top`

Comment: @n.osennij добавил скрин

Comment: и у вас там один mysqld. И расход памяти другой

Comment: @n.osennij да я как то раньше и не пользовался top. Попробую reboot сделать и посмотреть сколько сначала в top будет показываться.

Comment: по факту у вас скорее всего один mysqld. И это как бы копии одного и того же процесса, которые на самом деле не жрут каждый по столько, сколько написано было. Смотрите top

Comment: @n.osennij Сделал reboot, сделал новый скриншот, и разница ощутимая, почему так?

Comment: Да не такая уж и большая разница, имхо. Настраивать надо mysql точечно

Comment: @n.osennij Ну вы хотя бы какие не будь термины назовите что бы я уже изучать начал)

Comment: погуглите `mysql настройка`

Comment: Ситуация вполне обычная. И это не «процессы», а потоки. Если памяти сервера в целом хватает для нормальной работы всей системы - не трогайте ничего. Если есть желание расковырять mysql, то читайте про тюнинг pools and threads. И да, количество процессов в системе считают через вывод ps aux, а не top/htop